# How to implement pan, rotate, pinch, double tap gestures simultaneously in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, touch, gesture-recognition

I am working on a image processing project, where I need to drag image by pan, rotate image by rotation and make image smaller and bigger by pinch gestures end disable all the gestures by double tap. How to achieve this as I am very new to android development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: @Benito I downloaded the project. But it is not executing. Giving the compile time error as to configure the build path.

Comment: check this library http://www.aviary.com/android perhaps this will work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776360/513413

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418878/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-drag-using-androids-build-in-gesture-listener-and-s/19545542#19545542), does just that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/)

tutorial of pinch zoom, drag drop on canvas . may it help you.